# How to use Facebook php SDK in symfony?

Tags: php, facebook, symfony, facebook-graph-api

I'm using Symfony 5. I added officially recommended PHP SDK  https://github.com/facebookarchive/php-graph-sdk to the project using composer. I have a controller where I try to call it:

```php
class FacebookController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @var Facebook
     */
    private $facebook;

    public function __construct(Facebook $facebook)
    {
        $this->facebook = $facebook;
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {...}

}
```

But when I run this code, it says:
`Cannot autowire service "App\Controller\FacebookController": argument "$facebook" of method "__construct()" references class "Facebook\Facebook" but no such service exists.`
How to make the class Facebook "visible" for symfony?

Comment: Typically you would wrap the facebook library using what is known in the Symfony world as a bundle.  I made a quick search and did not find anything current but you could still take a look at them to get an idea of how to make an injectable facebook service.  Be aware that even the package you linked does not look like it has been touched in 3 years or so.

Comment: You can pretty easily make a class not in the default namespace/config available for [auto wiring](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html), but the config and further dependencies won’t be available unless you define them, too, which is what a bundle does. The easiest fix is to just explicitly use them in your main code as regular PHP classes, where you call `new` on things.

Comment: you could try to use composer to autoload the files https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#files

Answer (score 0):

It turned out, that we can't use that [SDK](https://github.com/facebookarchive/php-graph-sdk) recommended by Facebook, because the version of the Facebook graph API supported by the SDK is [2.10](https://github.com/facebookarchive/php-graph-sdk/blob/5.x/src/Facebook/Facebook.php#L61). Current last version of graph API is [12](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/). Facebook still supports older versions, but the lowest supported version of graph API is [5.0](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog). It will be outdated in a few days, so probably when you read this message, the last supported verion is 6.0.